# Newtonsoft Json .NET exception thrown

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Exception thrown:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Messages.ObjectDescription]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

If someone can figure it out I would appreciate the help. Basicly I instantiate a class called MessageSS, serialize it to a JSON string, then try to deserialize it and the exception gets thrown.

Here are my classes:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum MessageType
    {
        req_authenticate,
        c_data,
        req_state,
        c_cmd,
        resp_authenticate,
        s_cmd,
        s_data,
        resp_state,
        s_state
    }

public interface IData { }

    public abstract class Message
    {
        public MessageType type { get; set; }

        public virtual string GetJson()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
        }
    }

public class ObjectDescription
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }
        public Quality quality { get; set; }
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }

        public ObjectDescription(string _key, string _type, double _value, Quality _quality, DateTime _timestamp)
        {
            key = _key;
            type = _type;
            value = _value;
            quality = _quality;
            timestamp = _timestamp;
        }
    }

public class MessageSSData : IData
    {
        public State state { get; set; }
        public List<ObjectDescription> data { get; set; }

        public MessageSSData(State _state, List<ObjectDescription> _data)
        {
            state = _state;
            this.data = _data;
        }
    }

    public class MessageSS : Message
    {
        public MessageSSData data { get; set; }

        public MessageSS(State state, List<ObjectDescription> data)
        {
            type = MessageType.s_state;
            this.data = new MessageSSData(state, data);
        }
    }

//Here is the code that throws the exception:
MessageSS mm = new MessageSS(State.CONNECTING, new ObjectDescription[2] { new ObjectDescription("prvi", "tip1", 1.1, Quality.BAD, new DateTime()), 
                new ObjectDescription("drugi", "tip2", 1.2, Quality.GOOD, new DateTime()) }.ToList());
            string json2 = mm.GetJson();
            MessageSS mm2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageSS>(json2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a default constructor for the type you're deserializing into.

Otherwise, JSON.Net will try to deserialize into your constructor parameters, which don't match your JSON.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem :)